# How to add progress status of a downloading file in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, progress-bar, zsh, telegram-bot

I want to show(regularly update) my download/upload progress of a file on my telegram bot.

I'm using aria2 for downloading and rclone for uploading. And all I'm using is bash/shell script.

What I Tried, ofcrs not worked.

```
aria2c $url | text=$(grep '%') | curl -s "https://api.telegram.org/bot${TG_TOKEN}/editMessageText" --data "message_id=${msg_id}&text=DOWNLOADED ${text}&chat_id=${ch_id}&parse_mode=HTML&disable_web_page_preview=True"
```